# Are questions about national scholarships allowed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness

In my country a large portion of PhD students are funded by the APA (Australia Post Graduate Award).

I have a question about it's rules that I can't work out by just reading them (They are bound up into the federal government legislation that created the scholarship, and it is a bit legalise)

Would I be on topic?

I think perhaps it is off topic because, because it may be too localised? 
I know we don't offically have that reason anymore,
but I suspect if I asked a question about a scholarship only available at my university, it would be closed or at least downvoted.

A National scholarship on the other hand could be useful.

I'm sure I can chase this information down by other means, like talking to the scholarships office at my univeristy.
(Which I would do so, if I asked here and failed to get a answer -- and then make it a self answered question.)
But having it online on this site would make it googleable for anyone else with the same question.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic),

> You should not ask "a question that will help only me," but rather "a question that will help people like me." If your question is so limited as to be useful only to you, consider broadening the scope so others can learn from your question as well. As a general rule, if you're asking about a particular institution, course, or journal, it's likely your question is too limited in scope. Try to extract the fundamental question from the specific problem at hand.

A question about a scholarship that cannot be generalized beyond your university is too localized, and would be closed.

A question about a national scholarship is probably OK if it's a large-scale program (i.e. not something that funds one student a year.) As an example, we've had acceptable questions about the [NSF Graduate Research Fellowship Program](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/what-are-some-good-practices-for-applying-to-the-nsf-graduate-research-fellowshi), which is US-specific.